# Can I use my Sweden issued Schengen visa to go to France and Italy only?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, italy, bangladeshi-citizens

I am from Bangladesh and planning to visit Paris (7 days) and Rome (6 days) in August with my family. As I was a bit late in applying for a visa at the French Embassy, I got a visa from the Swedish Embassy, which takes much less time end to end. Now, if I enter the Schengen area through Paris and entirely skip Sweden, will we be allowed to enter?

Comment: How did you get Sweden to issue a visa without having plans to visit Sweden as a main destination? Did you just make something up?

Comment: Kind of that! I submitted the itinerary to Sweden embassy with plan where I will stay more time in Sweden than Paris. The problem is, my two friends are also visiting Paris at the same time and they will not visit Sweden. If I need to catch them up, I can only spend 1 or 2 days in Stockholm which I think is not worth in terms of cost and travel hassle.

Comment: If this comes to the attention of the border officers when you enter the Schengen area, your visa could be revoked, in which case you would be denied entry and sent home.  It is best to stick with the itinerary you presented in your visa application.

Comment: It's good that you admit that you basically lied on your visa application. It's bad that you did lie.

Answer (score 6):

You may make minor adjustments to your itinerary after the visa is granted.

You may not present a false itinerary in order to get a visa. If you are found out, the visa will be cancelled, and getting a new one any time in the future will be difficult.

Apparently you have lied to get the visa. phoog made a good suggestion in his comment: turn the lie into a fact and to follow the itinerary which you have submitted. Sweden is quite nice in August, beautiful coasts, beautiful islands.

Comment: Thanks o.m and phoog for your feedback. I also understand the situation and eventually booked hotel and flight to Stockholm accordingly though not confirmed yet. But at the same time, want to travel with a big group. So trying to give a second thought. My question is after getting visa, if I want to change my itinerary what is the procedure? After all, it is just for tourism purpose.

Comment: For **small** changes, you just do it. Bring documents like hotel reservations and return tickets with you in case there are questions at the border. For **large** changes on a single-entry visa, cancel the visa and apply for a new one.

Comment: And for any other changes, there's Mastercard. ;)